# Signal Correlation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I limitize signals with different cycle length to a fixed length or to make signal cycle length equal to each other. Please share your comments.
Thanks

```
file = genfromtxt('COMBINED DATA.csv', delimiter=',')
U1=file[1:10000,0]
U2=file[1:10000,1]
U3=file[1:10000,3]
```

In this scenario U1 signal completes its cycle after 1000 samples where U2 completes after 4000 samples, so how can I make them equal so they follow the same number of samples to complete their cycle?

Kindly follow below link for dataset and image:
Image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19x99mhsd4H4nMgf4lgOjL7WpGLTrgByk
Dataset:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ROw-rAOerRl_a8L1ejcQJxaZYRSFIP7AgkH6myOmrhs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scipy.signal.resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) for that.

```
# Generate a signal with 100 data point

import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
x = np.sin(t)

# Downsample it by a factor of 4

from scipy import signal
x_resampled = signal.resample(x, 25)

# Plot

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
plt.plot(t, x, label='Original signal')
plt.plot(t[::4], x_resampled, 'ko', label='Resampled signal')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

(Code from http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_resample.html)